# Resulting Shape for advanced indexing in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

When indexing a numpy array with multiple arrays of the same size, the behavior depends on the position of the indexed axes.

- If the axes are next to each other the axis is added at the position of the indexed arrays.
- If the axes are not next to each other the new axis is added at the beginning of the array.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
print(a[:, [0, 1], [0, 1], :, :].shape)       # (4, 2, 7, 8)
print(a[:, [0, 1], :, [0, 1], :].shape)       # (2, 4, 6, 8)
print(a[:, [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], :].shape)  # (4, 2, 8)
print(a[:, [0, 1], [0, 1], :, [0, 1]].shape)  # (2, 4, 7)
```

My problem is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939602/numpy-indexing-reorders-array) and the mentioned [PR](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6075) in the answer.
But it seems that this `oindex` is not yet available.

What options do I have to achieve a consistent behavior? For example, always add the new axis at the beginning no matter if there is a `:` in between or not.

Comment: What's a consistent behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a clear case of the ambiguity that combined advanced and  basic indexing produces.  The link is a less ambiguous case, involving a list and scalar.

With

```
a[:, [0, 1], :, [0, 1], :]
```

the 5 and 7 are contracted to 2, but what order should it use?

```
(4, 2, 6, 8)
(4, 6, 2, 8)
```

Faced with this kind of ambiguity, `numpy` developers opted to put it first

```
(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

As can be seen from the NEP/PR this issue is not simple, and has not been resolved.

Comment: Yes I agree. Adding the new axis in the beginning is reasonable. But I find it strange that this is not the case for `a[:, [0, 1], [0, 1], :, :]`

Comment: But in that case there isn't that ambiguity, since the 2 (or 3) contracting dimensions are together.

Comment: Yes you are righty. However if you see it as an operation with the two axis i and j as input, I would prefer not to have different behaviour for the case  j=i+1.